# Why does rendering my blender scene use all my space?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

basically the issue here is I have a pretty heavy nature scene, and when I go to rendered mode it takes all my storage space and doesn't end up rendering is just says "system is out of GPU and shared host memory." Not sure what to do here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean its exactly as stated, its just taking all 10 gb of my storage space

Comment: Does the issue persist when you render it out Frame by frame instead of as one clip?

Comment: Apologies I don't understand